# Syntax logic behind ++ with respect to references and as a return value

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

```
int f3(int i, int j) {
    int& k = i;
    ++j;
    return ++k;
}
int main()
{
    int i = 2, j = 4, k;
    k = f3(i, j);
    cout << "i: " << i << " j: " << j << " k: " << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

why do I get `i = 2` and `k = 3`. I mean surely because I have set `int& k = i`, both i and k are in essence the same variable as they share the same memory space. Can anyone explain why this is so in simple english? Or what am I not understanding?

Comment: You are passing `i` by value. So whatever you do with `i` or its reference `k` in `f3` is not reflected back.

Comment: And what do you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you set `i` to `2`:

```
int i=2,
```

And here you pass the `i`:

```
k=f3(i,j);
```

However, you're passing a **copy** of the `i`:

```
int f3(int i, int j) // you need a "&" in here too if you want to pass the reference
```

So in this line:

```
int& k = i;
```

You set `k` to be a reference to the **copy** of `i`. Thus when you change it, the actual `i` from `main` isn't changed.

Instead, try this:

```
int f3(int &i, int j) { // now you're pssing a reference to i, not a copy thereof
```

And your output value for `i` will be `3`. For a nice example of call by reference, see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm).

Answer (score 1):

`int f3(int i, int j)`

Parameter `i` is passed as value. So the variable `i` declared in `main` and the parameter `i` in the function are different variables. You need to pass `i` as reference to make it the reference if `i` declared in `main`.

`int f3(int &i, int j)`

Answer (score 1):

You pass the arguments *by value*.

The variable `k` is only referencing the *local* variable `i` inside the `f3` function.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that i and k are in essence the same variable.
However, in this line `int f3(int i, int j)` you have passed your variable `i` by value, not by reference. This means that whatever modifications you make to `i` in your function, they will not be saved in `int main()`.

```
int f3(int i, int j) {
   int& k = i; // k = 2 and it's a reference to the local variable i
   ++j; 
   return ++k; // k = 3, local variable i = 3
} 

int main() { 
   int i = 2, j = 4, k;
   k = f3(i, j); // k = 3, i and j are unchanged because they were passed by value
   cout << "i: " << i << " j: " << j << " k: " << k << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

What you have done here `int& k = i;`, you created a reference `k` to a local variable `i`, which is just a copy of the variable `i` from your `int main()`.
Basically, `k` does no harm to `i` from `int main()`.